# User cannot see dashboard

Tags: dashboard

I created a dashboard, and I saved it in my "UserDashboards" folder. I provided "Read only" access to this folder to the following public group "DashboardUserGroup". I have two users in this group: "Hannah Smith" and "Andy Barlow". Hannah can see the dashboard and Andy cannot see it.

I am completely lost as to why Andy cannot see the dashboard. They have exactly the same user profile, they are both members of that group.

Regards, Lily.

Comment: Are you 100% sure they have the same profile and possibly permission sets?

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure. And the strange thing, in our sandbox this user can see the folder, and in prod they cannot! I compared their sandbox and live profile, and user detail page, permissions and the folder permissions. They are 100% the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really sorry, but we have two public groups that have nearly the same name - only one letter difference, and that user was not a member of that public group. problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

it may  be moved by Hannah in his/her own folder, that's way its only visible to Hannah, 
please check your file/ Dashboard's Location, and move back to UserDashboards folder